# Problem running bundle install in MacOS terminal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

When running `bundle install`, I get the error

```
There was an error while trying to write to
'/Users/my-user/.bundle/cache/compact_index/rubygems.org.443.29b0360b937aa4d161703e6160654e47/versions'.
It is likely that you need to grant write permissions for that path.
```

I am on Ruby version 2.3.3 using platform `x86_64-darwin18`.
Are they any suggestions on how to fix this error?

I have already tried unlocking the file, but it says that the file cannot be unlocked and only provides me with the opportunity to make a duplicate copy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try,

1) `chown -R USERNAME /Users/my-user/.bundle/cache/compact_index/`

2) `sudo bundle install`

3) `bundle exec bundle install`

4) Just give the permission to `chown -R USERNAME /Users/my-user/.bundle/cache/`

5) `rm -rf /Users/my-user/.bundle/cache`

Replace the USERNAME with your system username

Comment: after running that and then attempting to do `bundle install` again, I got the same error

Comment: @peopleplusme can you please try `sudo bundle install` or `bundle exec bundle install`, else just give the permission to `chown -R USERNAME /Users/my-user/.bundle/cache/` or `rm -rf  /Users/my-user/.bundle/cache`